# App unfortunately Crashing

Tags: java, android

```
//I'm new to programming and android studio
package com.example.calc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import static com.example.calc.R.id.editText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText editTexts = (EditText) findViewById(editText);
double a = 0.0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                                                   //Buttons to take input and display
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

                                          //using to make the buttons react
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
}
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){

        double res;     //Display and taking input from same textfield

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTexts.getText().toString())) {
            return;
        }

        res = Double.parseDouble(editTexts.getText().toString());

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                a += res;
                editTexts.setText(" ");
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                a -= res;
                editTexts.setText(" ");
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                a *= res;
                editTexts.setText(" ");
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                a /= res;
                editTexts.setText(" ");
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                editTexts.setText((int) a);
                break;
            case R.id.button6:
                a = 0.0;
                editTexts.setText(" ");
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, App crashed.
Gradle is building but crashing as soon as opening.
How to resolve this error??

```
logCat:
    06-24 22:36:42.926 4983-4983/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown 
    /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
    06-24 22:36:42.926 4983-4983/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel 
    missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
    06-24 22:36:42.930 4983-4983/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already 
    on)
    06-24 22:36:43.400 4983-4983/com.example.calc I/InstantRun: starting instant 
    run server: is main process
    06-24 22:36:43.626 4983-4983/com.example.calc W/art: Verification of boolean 

  android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.initializePanelContent(android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$PanelFeatureState) took 139.729ms
06-24 22:36:43.741 4983-4983/com.example.calc W/art: Verification of 
    android.support.v7.view.ActionMode 


 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode$Callback) took 109.701ms
06-24 22:36:43.743 4983-4983/com.example.calc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                --------- beginning of crash
    06-24 22:36:43.746 4983-4983/com.example.calc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
    EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: 
    com.example.calc, PID: 4983

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example.calc/com.example.calc.MainActivity}: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
     'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null 
     object reference
                                                                    at 

    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                                                                     at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                    at 
      android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                    at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                    at 
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at 
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                    at 
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at 




 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                    at 
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                 Caused by: 
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null 
    object reference
                                                                    at 
     android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>
    (AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
                                                                    at 
     android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>
    (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:152)
                                                                    at 
    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>
    (AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                                                                    at 
    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>
    (AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                                    at 
     android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:204)
                                                                    at 
     android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:184)
                                                                    at 


 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:518
    )
                                                                    at 

  android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:189
    )
                                                                    at 
    com.example.calc.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:15)
                                                                    at 
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                    at 
     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                                    at 
     android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
                                                                    at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
                                                                    at 
      android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                    at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                    at 
     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                    at 
      android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at 
      android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                    at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                    at 
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at 
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at 




 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                    at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: It may help to read: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped.
 How can I solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Edited, but can't understand any of this,tnx for replying

Comment: The diclaration of Views [EditText editTexts = (EditText) findViewById(editText);] belongs in onCreate

Comment: Tnx it solved. I typed this statement in both oncreate and onClickListener